# PC doesn't boot after disabling CSM

Tags: boot

I have an ASRock b450 pro4 mainboard and I want to disable CSM so I can enable Secure Boot.
The problem is, my PC won't start up / it goes straight into the BIOS, do I need to change anything else?

Comment: Yes, you need to install the OS or OSes properly in UEFI mode. And if Windows then likely reformat the whole drive as GPT because Windows has strict requirements: GPT for UEFI mode and MBR ("DOS" or "msdos") for BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode.

Comment: CSM enabled means your disk is partitioned MBR, that is unsupported by UEFI. In order to boot with CSM disabled you either need to repartition/reinstall or use `mbr2gpt` and hope that it doesn't fail and mean you have to repartition/reinstall anyway. https://superuser.com/a/1680510/19943

Comment: MBR2GPT has specific requirements for it to work, check those requirements, BEFORE you attempt to do the conversion.  If those requirements are NOT meet, then perform the appropriate steps, to resolve those conflicts.